# How to get the "effective pom" from nexus rest API (or programmatically)

Tags: java, rest, maven, pom.xml, nexus

I'm interested in the effective pom of a maven artifact preferably via nexus rest api.
I know there is a way to get it with maven help plugin with

```
mvn help:effective-pom
```

However, i need the effective pom within a webapp - actually within a confluence plugin (which is an OSGI bundle) and afaik i can not run a maven plugin in this context.
My "plugin" has a rest client querying nexus - so i can easy fetch the "normal" pom but not the effective, however probably i missed one of the nexus rest resources.

We are using 
*"Sonatype Nexus Professional" version 2.11.4-01, api version 2.11.4-01*.

Would be fine for me to get the effective pom programmatically with Java, but i have no clue how to achieve it. I "need" the effective pom because it contains a link to the maven generated site which is build during release process. I'd like to have a (confluence) macro who creates a link to the site on nexus.

Comment: I don't think you can realistically construct an effective POM without invoking Maven itself, given the fact that your `settings.xml` and your environment variables affect the result. The obvious question is: why do you need the effective POM in the first place?

Comment: By the way ... i also asked the same question in sonatype support. The answer was:
_This isn't possible, there is no REST API for this. You need to use the maven help plugin to get the effective pom, or use the class it uses. As I recall this i org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver._

Comment: @biziclop I've edited the initial post to explain the reason for what i wanted the effective pom. (It contains the link to the maven generated site.)

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to get effective pom:

```
1. Request the effective pom artifact from Nexus (if it was produced and deployed previously)

2. Request the sources artifact from Nexus and execute over the source code:
mvn help:effective-pom > my_effective_pom.xml
```

Nexus was designed as a storage service, it just storages items and does not modify them